# Scheme List Function : Where am i wrong?

Tags: function, scheme, racket

I am new to Scheme and I am trying to write a function which return a descending prefix of a list. Can someone explain where am I wrong with my code? I tested it with `(prefix (list 3 2 1 5))` and I continuously get this error:

```
cdr: contract violation
expected: pair?
given: '()
```

```
(define (prefix lst)
  (define (prefix-helper kur result)
    (let((next (car(cdr lst))))
    (if (<= (car lst) next) result
        ((prefix-helper (cdr kur) (cons next result))))))
  (prefix-helper lst (car lst)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 4 errors in your code.

1. You are probably using `lst` in your helper, which is the same during the whole process, while you probably should be using `kur` which is the rest of the list at each iteration. Because of this your base condition does not hit on any of the iterations. This is probably the root cause of the error you are seeing.
2. A list where there is no element that is smaller or equal to the next element you don't check if `kur` is `null?`. Doing `(cdr kur)` when `kur` is `null?` signals a contract violation since `cdr` should always be presented a pair. This is the error you are seeing.
3. There are parentheses around `prefix-helper` in the alternative to `if`. That means that the result of the recursion is assumed to be another function that is then applied. Since `result` is a list structure it will signal an `application: not a procedure` if it doesn't fail on other errors first.
4. You start off the helper with the first element. That means your result becomes a dotted list eg. `(1 2 . 3)`. If this wasn't intended then you should start it with a list with the first element instead of just the element.

Answer (score 0):

Use of 'named let' may help clarify the steps:

```
(define (prefix lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst)                  ; starting with full list
             (pf '()))                  ; empty prefix list
    (cond
      [(empty? lst)                     ; if list over, return prefix list
       (reverse pf)]       

      [(or (empty? pf)                  ; if just starting or 
           (< (first lst) (first pf)))  ; still descending
       (loop (rest lst)                 ; add element to prefix list and 
             (cons (first lst) pf))]    ; loop again with rest of the list

      [else                             ; if not descending, return prefix list; 
       (reverse pf)]
      )))
```